# Como mostrar una fila de un datagridview en los textbox de otro form? c#

Tags: c#

lo que intento hacer es sacar una fila completa de un DataGridView y mostrarla en otro form, es para un botón de buscar, quiero escribir el nombre y que al seleccionarlo en el gridview y presionar el botón me aparezcan esos datos en otro form.
Aquí esta el Datagrid de donde extraeré la fila:

```
    string Nombre, Id, fecha;
    double Sueldo, incentivo, result;
    DataGridView filas;
    public Form5(double subru, string nom, string id, double incen, string fech, DataGridView filas, double resultado)
        : this()
    {
        result = resultado;
        Nombre = nom;
        Id = id;
        Sueldo = subru;
        incentivo = incen;
        fecha = fech;
        this.filas = filas;
    }

    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea Salir?", "Salir", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 fd = new Form1(dgv2);
        fd.Visible = true;
        Visible = false;
    }

    private void btndatos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (filas != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < filas.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewRow clonedRow = (DataGridViewRow)filas.Rows[i].Clone();
                for (Int32 index = 0; index < filas.Rows[i].Cells.Count; index++)
                {
                    clonedRow.Cells[index].Value = filas.Rows[i].Cells[index].Value;
                }

                dgv2.Rows.Add(clonedRow);
            }
        }
        dgv2.Rows.Add(fecha, dateTimePicker2, dateTimePicker3, Id, Nombre, Sueldo, incentivo, result);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenid@, Rax. ¿Cómo sería la vista de todo esto? Lo siento, no me queda claro con la explicación, me enreda un poco. Y en cuanto al código del Form1 ¿ese formulario sería el que recibiría la fila enviada?

Comment: El segundo formulario, donde vas a enviar los datos, está abierto o lo vas a abrir al enviar los datos? ya sabes obtener los datos de tu datagrid? Intenta mejorar un poco la pregunta porque no queda claro del todo el escenario ni en que punto estás

Answer (score 2):

Supongamos que tienes dos formularios Form1 y Form2.

> Nota: Debes crear los elementos datagriedView, textboxes y botones 
>   que menciono en la solución dada mas abajo, si hago referencia a un
>   boton dentro del code behind del formulario, debes haberlo creado
>   ('**arrastrar los elementos utilizando la paleta de herramientas en visual studio**')

**Form1:** El cual posee tu datagriedview y con el cual deseas pasar los datos hacia Form2 antes o luego de haber filtrado el datagriedView.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /*
            Declaramos una variable de tipo datatable para manejar los datos en nuestro datagriedView
         */
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        /*
            Cargamos los datos a nuestro DatagriedView
         */
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("pais", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Belgica" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Francia" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Italia" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "España" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "Estados Unidos" });
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        /*
           Evento Click del boton buscar
         */
        private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("pais LIKE '%{0}%'", txtBuscar.Text);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        /*
            Evento change del texbox Buscar
         */
        private void txtBuscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBuscar.Text))
            {
                dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;

            }
        }

        /*
            Evento donde tomaremos la fila seleccionada y le pasaremos los datos al formulario 2
         */
        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string id = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
            string pais = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Pais"].Value.ToString();

            Form2 frm2 = new Form2(id, pais);
            frm2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2: El cual posee los campos que quieres recibir desde el Form1. En este caso solo se reciben el Id y el pais.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        /*
         Estas variables serviran de contenedor para recibir los valores desde el form1
        */
        static string Id;
        static string Pais;

        /*
            Se reciben los valores en el constructor del formulario 2 para asignarle 
            dichos valores a las variables staticas definidas
        */
        public Form2(string id, string pais)
        {
            Id = id;
            Pais = pais;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /*
          AL mostrarse el formulario le asignamos los valores de las variables estaticas antes modificadas
       */
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            txtId.Text = Id;
            txtPais.Text = Pais;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dejame intentarlo a ver

Comment: no entiendo la parte donde se cargan los datos

Comment: @Raxthegood en primer lugar debes tener los elementos ya creados para que pueda funcionar la solucion, la parte de cargar los datos hace uso del datagriedView que ya tienes agregado en el formulario, modificare mi respuesta para que lo tomes en consideración